# Running R scripts in Airflow?

Tags: r, airflow

Is it possible to run an R script as an airflow dag? I have tried looking online for documentation on this and am unable to do so. Thanks

Comment: You should include some code you'd like to execute. IMO I think Pierre's answer is the best so far and in the absence of code should be accepted. You can just include `bash my_shell_script.sh` in your Airflow DAG and then in that bash script use RScript to execute your R file.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to containerize your R script and run it using the DockerOperator, which is included in the standard distribution.  This removes the need to have your worker nodes configured with the correct version of R and any needed R libraries.

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to be a R Operator right now.

You could either write your own and contribute to the community or simply run your task as a BashOperator calling RScript.

Answer (score 4):

USe BashOperator for executing R scripts.
For example:
opr_hello = BashOperator(task_id='xyz',bash_command='Rscript Pathtofile/file.r')

Answer (score 2):

There is a pull request open for an R operator, still waiting for it to be incorporated.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/3115/files

Answer (score 0):

Combining the approaches from other answers, you can run an R script in a Docker container without bundling it into the container by calling it in a DAG using the BashOperator like this task:

```
    process_data = BashOperator(
        task_id='process_data',
        bash_command = 'docker run --rm=true -v /home/myuser/airflow/dags/source/my_r_project_folder:/source rocker/verse:4.3 Rscript /source/my_r_script.R'
        )
    process_data
```

This mounts the directory `/home/myuser/airflow/dags/source/my_r_project_folder` as a volume so that the R script and any data files are present in the container, then executes the file `my_r_script.R` from that `/source` directory using the environment defined by the [rocker/verse image](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/verse).  For reproducibility, you would ideally specify a certain tag for that image, in this case 4.3.

My Airflow instance is running in Docker itself and is starting sibling containers using the host machine's socket.  A different setup might need to handle the mounting of a volume somewhat differently.